# Does each of java API function map to java native method?

Tags: java

Does each of java API function map to java native method?

If not then how those functions get the functions of operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of them do, and others build on top of the former (or on functionality offered by the JVM itself). Only very few methods map directly to native code, as it is platform specific, and the whole point of the JVM is to offer a platform neutral stage for the code to run.

Answer (score 1):

A Java program runs in a JVM: Java Virtual Machine. The actual executed program is the JVM (lauched by the `java` command). This JVM is written in C and/or C++. Its role is to load Java byte-code, interpret it (and compile it to native code), and run it.

Some Java methods have the `native` modifier, and this means that they don't contain any byte-code to execute, but are directly mapped to a native function written in C or C++.

Answer (score 0):

No, as you can see in the source code or by decompilation. The truth is, only very few methods map to native code.

Answer (score 0):

Think about your question it doesn't make complete sense as not all functions (methods) use functions of the operating system.